# Stack Overflow and Code Review not displaying correctly

Tags: support, google-chrome, internet-explorer

For some reason only Meta SE is displaying correctly in my Internet browsers.

Screenshot of Stack Overflow:

[image: Stack Overflow ScreenShot]

The same occurs with *[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Music Practice and Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/tour)* and *[Super User](https://superuser.com/tour)*.

I don't understand all the working of website sites, etc. Can anyone give me a hint as to why this is happening?

I normally use Chrome, current version *Version 48.0.2564.82 m*.

Comment: are you using any browser plugins? are you behind a corporate firewall?

Comment: what do you see here: http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=d9e4e43243243242

Comment: Error Code: 502 Proxy Error. Forefront TMG denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL). (12202).
IP Address: 172.17.94.40
Date: 2016/01/21 11:26:32 AM [GMT]
Server: MWPTMG01.elec.eskom.co.za
Source: proxy

Comment: @Sklivvz Thats the Info for support personal. There will be a corperate firewall. Plugins Adobe Flash Player - Version: 20.0.0.286, Native Client, 
Chrome PDF Viewer, Widevine Content Decryption Module

Comment: Forefront TMG denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL).  Tell Forefront to GFH (or is it GFI?)

Comment: It was actually working a bit this afternoon but stopped after a period of time again

Answer (score 5):

Our sites are served through two main locations:

- the actual websites at (e.g.) stackoverflow.com which contain only the *text* of the pages
- a static resource website at http://cdn.sstatic.net/ which contains images, style, and other resources.

This is an optimization due to the way browsers work.

Apparently you are behind a misconfigured firewall which is letting through the first website but blocking the second website.

You can see that this is the case in this error you reported:

> Error Code: 502 Proxy Error. Forefront TMG denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL). (12202). IP Address: 172.17.94.40 Date: 2016/01/21 11:26:32 AM [GMT] Server: MWPTMG01.elec.eskom.co.za Source: proxy

You need to ask your internal support to allow connections to `*.sstatic.net` on HTTP and HTTPS ports in the "Forefront TMG" instance running on `MWPTMG01.elec.eskom.co.za`.